# select records with max date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below :

```
Id  fkEmp_id  Date          Type
1     1       2016-08-20      1
2     2       2016-08-28      1
3     2       2016-08-30      0
```

I want to  select  records based on "Type"  <>  0 and the " Date " should be Maximum  Date  for each employees.

I try the query below :

```
select *  from table where Type <> 0 and fkEmp_Id = 2 order by max(Date)
```

But the result is look like below :

```
 Id  fkEmp_id   Date           Type 
  2    2         2016-08-28     1
```

If the Type is 1 and the Date is Max for each FkEmp_id then only I want to fetch the records . How to do that? Please help me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your desired result set, and if the logic for generating it is not clear, please explain.

Comment: You will find this useful: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple typical aggregate [(GROUP BY) query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
 SELECT MAX(Date) as MaxDate, fkEmp_id  
   FROM table
  WHERE Type <> 0
  GROUP BY fkEmp_id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . but it will retrun  2 row only. i want the Type is not equal to 0 and the Date should be the maximum . if the condition is okay then only return values

Answer (score 1):

So, start with a query that gets the "maximum date" for each employee fkemp_id.

Then use that query as an inline view. Join that to the original table to filter out all rows except the rows where type<>0 and date matches the "maximum date" for the given fkemp_id.

For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.fkemp_id
     , t.date
     , t.type
  FROM ( -- inline view query to return maximum date for each fkemp_id
         SELECT n.fkemp_id
              , MAX(n.date) AS max_date
           FROM mytable n
          GROUP BY n.fkemp_id
       ) m
  JOIN mytable t
    ON t.fkemp_id = m.fkemp_id
   AND t.date     = m.max_date
   AND t.type    <> 0
 ORDER BY t.fkemp_id
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why this answer received a downvote. (I think it would be beneficial to OP and future readers to identify *why* this answer is incorrect or unhelpful.) There are a couple ways to interpret the OP specification. This answer is based on one interpretation, the one I believe OP is trying to achieve... first... exclude all rows where the `date` is not the latest date for each fkemp_id. And from the remaining rows, return only those that have `type<>0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery as follows:

```
SELECT max(date), fkemp_id from emp
where fkemp_id not in (Select fkemp_id from emp where type = 0)
GROUP by fkemp_id
```